# streamlit.text_area configurability

Tags: python, streamlit

I wanted to know 2 things.

1. Is it was possible to change the size (length and breadth) of the text_area created by `streamlit.text_area()` method? If yes, how?
2. Then my second doubt is regarding this code:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.title('Text analyser')
TextBox = st.text_area('Enter text here...')

if st.button('Analyse'):
    st.write(TextBox)
```

when I enter this in the text area:

```
Hello
this is a test message
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

The output is a single line i.e. `Hello this is a test message line 1 line 2 line 3`.
How can I make sure that the output is in separate lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the height:

```
streamlit.text_area(label, value='', height=None, max_chars=None, key=None)
```

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#streamlit.text_area

The output is preserving the newlines, just that using st.write renders it as though there's no newline in html. You can check with a `print()` in your streamlit code or even inspect the actual element in the browser.

Comment: Could you also help me resolve the second issue?

Comment: Like I said, second one is not an issue. Newlines are preserved. What are you actually trying to do with it?

Comment: I am trying to make a text analyzer in Streamlit. it gives basic information about the text and I want it to return the number of lines. But I am dropping the Line Count plan. thanks for your help

Comment: It's just the rendering of the newlines when streamlit outputs the HTML. One way to "retain" (the display) of newlines is to use `st.markdown()`, if you are familiar with markdown and prefer having some control over formatting.

for Line Count, you can do a python split on `\n` (or other fancier way of parsing lines) and return `len` of the output.